# delete consecutive nodes with same name

Tags: xslt

I am trying to use XSLT to transform following xml:

```
 <level>
    <nextlevel>
        <note> text text text </note>
    </nextlevel>
    <nextlevel> 
        <abc>
        </abc>
        <note>bla bla bla </note>
        <note>bla bla bla bla bla</note>
        <xyz>
        </xyz>
    </nextlevel>
    <nextlevel>
        <note> text text text </note>
    </nextlevel>
</level>
```

I want to remove the duplicate nodes "note" only when it appears twice consecutively. The output should look like:

```
<level>
 <nextlevel>
    <note> text text text </note>
 </nextlevel>
  <nextlevel>   
    <abc>
    </abc>
    <xyz>
    </xyz>
 </nextlevel>
 <nextlevel>
    <note> text text text </note>
 </nextlevel>
</level>
```

I am using the following xslt:

```
<xsl:key name="dup" match="note" use="concat(generate-id(..), '|', name())"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note[not(generate-id() = generate-id(key('dup', concat(generate-id(..), '|', .))[1]))]"/>
```

However, all the nodes with name "note" are being deleted, what is wrong with my xslt?

Comment: You hav used a key with name "dup" .. but it is not defined in xslt

Answer (score 0):

Try using this  this will avoid repetition of consecutive node of same name with same value

```
 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>  

      <xsl:template match="*[not(*)][name() = preceding-sibling::*[1]/name()][@value = preceding-sibling::*[1]/@value]" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but the above code gives the following error:
 msxml3.dll: NodeTest expected here.

Answer (score 0):

Using XSLT 1.0 here is one suggestion:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  version="1.0"
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note[(preceding-sibling::*[1][not(self::note)] or not(preceding-sibling::*[1]))
                          and following-sibling::*[1][self::note]
                          and (following-sibling::*[2][not(self::note)] or not(following-sibling::*[2]))]"/>

<xsl:template match="note[preceding-sibling::*[1][self::note]
                          and (preceding-sibling::*[2][not(self::note)] or not(preceding-sibling::*[2]))
                          and (following-sibling::*[1][not(self::note)] or not(following-sibling::*[1]))]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to the input

```
 <level>
    <nextlevel>
        <note> text text text </note>
    </nextlevel>
    <nextlevel> 
        <abc>
        </abc>
        <note>bla bla bla </note>
        <note>bla bla bla bla bla</note>
        <xyz>
        </xyz>
    </nextlevel>
    <nextlevel>
        <note> text text text </note>
    </nextlevel>
    <nextlevel>
        <foo>bar</foo>
        <note>...</note>
        <note>...</note>
        <note>...</note>
        <note>...</note>
        <bar>baz</bar>
    </nextlevel>
</level>
```

it outputs

```
<level>
    <nextlevel>
        <note> text text text </note>
    </nextlevel>
    <nextlevel>
        <abc>
        </abc>


        <xyz>
        </xyz>
    </nextlevel>
    <nextlevel>
        <note> text text text </note>
    </nextlevel>
    <nextlevel>
        <foo>bar</foo>
        <note>...</note>
        <note>...</note>
        <note>...</note>
        <note>...</note>
        <bar>baz</bar>
    </nextlevel>
</level>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to remove the duplicate nodes "note" only when it appears twice
>   consecutively.

Perhaps this could be simply:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="note[count(../note) > 1]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This will remove any `note` that has another `note` as a sibling. If it's important that the notes be *consecutive*, you could change the removing template to:

```
<xsl:template match="note[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::note] or following-sibling::node()[1][self::note]]"/>
```